# How do I get excess liquid out of a carpenter?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-forestry

I want to craft something that requires water, but there is residual seed oil in my carpenter. How do I get it out?

Comment: Let him go to the bathroom?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the pipette. It'll remain in the pipette for re-use later (or for any other forestry machine e.g. the BioGasEngine). The display of the pipette is a little bit buggy though.

But - it's a pain in the ass because you need one pipette for every type of liquid. I prefer using a carpenter for each type of liquid.

The third way should be pumping the liquid out using liquid pipes - but I haven't tried that.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured this one out. You can use a pipette, but unless the liquid is honey, you will lose it.